# Project Euler #4 - Largest Palindrome Product

Tags: python, optimization, project-euler

> A palindromic number reads the same both ways. The largest palindrome
>   made from the product of two 2-digit numbers is 9009 = 91 × 99.
>
> Find the largest palindrome made from the product of two 3-digit
>   numbers.

How would you improve the following code?

I'm looking specifically for:

- performance optimizations
- ways to shorten the code
- more "pythonic" ways to write it

---

```
   def is_palindrome(num):
        return str(num) == str(num)[::-1]        
    def fn(n):
        max_palindrome = 1
        for x in range(n,1,-1):
            if x * n < max_palindrome: 
                break
            for y in range(n,x-1,-1):
                if is_palindrome(x*y) and x*y > max_palindrome:
                    max_palindrome = x*y
                elif x * y < max_palindrome:
                    break
        return max_palindrome

    print fn(999)
```

Comment: whenever a `product` or `combination` or `permutation` is mentioned, i'd check `itertools` first

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function `is_palindrome` converts `num` to a string twice. You might consider:

```
def is_palindrome(n):
   """Return True if n is a palindrome; False otherwise."""
   s = str(n)
   return s == s[::-1]
```

And then for the main loop I would write:

```
from itertools import product
max(x * y for x, y in product(range(1000), repeat=2) if is_palindrome(x * y))
```

This runs in less than a second so I think it is not worth putting lots of effort into optimizing it.

Answer (score 1):

It looks good to me.

You could break from the inner loop even if x*y == max to avoid 1) an additional useless iteration 2) checking if it is a palindrome. Also it would remove some code testing the value of the product.

I think you could change the limits of the inner loop to consider only y smaller or equal to x. If you do so, you can break out of the outer loop if x*x < max.

**Edit :**

Some more details. My second optimisation tips is not a really a good tip, it's not a bad tip neither.

Here is the function before and after taking my second comment into action. Also, some more basic code has been added for benchmarking purposes.

```
def fn(n):
    itx,ity = 0, 0
    max_palindrome = 1
    for x in range(n,1,-1):
        itx+=1
        if x * n < max_palindrome:
            break
        for y in range(n,x-1,-1):
            ity+=1
            if is_palindrome(x*y) and x*y > max_palindrome:
                max_palindrome = x*y
            elif x * y < max_palindrome:
                break
    print "1", n,itx,ity,max_palindrome
    return max_palindrome

def fn2(n):
    itx,ity = 0, 0
    max_palindrome = 1
    for x in range(n,1,-1):
        itx+=1
        if x * x <= max_palindrome:
            break
        for y in range(x,1,-1):
            ity+=1
            if x*y <= max_palindrome:
                break
            if is_palindrome(x*y):
                max_palindrome = x*y
                break
    print "2", n,itx,ity,max_palindrome
    return max_palindrome
```

Now, when running the following tests :

```
for n in [99,999,9999,99999,999999]:
    assert fn(n) == fn2(n)
```

fn is sometimes in a pretty epic way, sometimes just worse...

```
fn n      itx    ity result
1 99       10     38 9009
2 99        6     29 9009
1 999      93   3242 906609
2 999      48   6201 906609
1 9999    100   4853 99000099
2 9999     51   2549 99000099
1 99999   339  50952 9966006699
2 99999   171 984030 9966006699
1 999999 1000 498503 999000000999
2 999999  501 250499 999000000999
```

Comment: are you sure the second optimization is correct?

Comment: Assuming x goes from n to 0 and y goes from x to 0, I think we have the following property: 1) for a given x, x*y is decreasing 2) if x*x <= max, x*y <= x*x <= max.

Comment: y is in the range [n..x-1]. y*x > x*x  for y > x

Comment: This is why I think you could/should change the range you are using for y and consider only 0 <= y <= x except if you have a reason not to.

Comment: that's a change which leads to an incorrect algorithm (as written above, it would miss some of the larger palindromes, including the correct solution). It would be an effective optimization if i was writing an algorithm looking for the smallest palindrome, though

Comment: I've added more details about what I had in mind.

Comment: Both the functions you are testing above are incorrect. Remove your optimization from my version of the function, and test that against your version.

Comment: I am not sure which optimisation you are talking about. I've tried copy pasting your version and I do get the same results. Please let me know if I've missed something.

Comment: sorry, misread the code, your algorithms are correct

Comment: No worries. Can my answer be upvoted so that it doesn't get a negative reputation whilst being mostly right ?